# The order of columns in a sparse matrix multiplication with a vector

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I wish to multiply a huge sparse matrix `A` with a binary vector `y`, i.e., `A.dot(y)`. However, in order to calculate `y` I need to know the order of the columns in `A` -- to make sure columns correspond both in `A` and `y` before the multiplication. I couldn't find a way to figure out what would be "the order of columns" in the `dot()` operation, so I need to verify `y` is ordered the same as `A`. How can I do that efficiently?

`A` is a CSR matrix in the format `csr_matrix(data, indices, indptr)`. Working with a dense `A` is not possible. I have a solution with looping, but I want to avoid it if possible since `A` has 11M rows and 8M columns.

Comment: They're in whatever order they're in. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to figure out.

Comment: True, but think about a scenario where you need to calculate/generate y manually. Then, in order that dot() will work properly, you need to know what is the i-th column corresponding the i-th cell in y.

Comment: If you're calculating `B = A (dot) y` then `B[0] = A[0,0] * y[0] + A[0, 1] * y[1] + ... + A[0, n] * y[n] ` and so on. The matrix does not have axis labels, it only has row and column index.

Comment: Experiment with a small matrix, one where you can test both the sparse and dense calculations.  `A.dot(v)` should give the same values (the sparse result may be `np.matrix`).  The sparse code takes care of matching sparse columns with the `y` array elements.